# Determine the Cumulative Distributive Distribution(CDF) of a truncated value?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

[image: Question]

It is the last part(part h) that I am having problems with.

I know you use integration and then split it into 2 parts.

But how exactly do you do it ? A detailed answer would be very helpful !

Please help !

Answer (score 2):

For $u\lt b$, $F_U(u)=F_Y(u)$.

For $u\ge b$, $F_U(u)=1$.  For whenever $Y\ge b$, we have $U=b$. It follows that $U\le b$ always.

That's all there is to it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For the second case why is it 1 ?That's the part where I am stuck. Could you please explain ?

Comment: You are welcome. Note that $U$ has a positive mass (probability) concentrated at the point $b$, so it cannot be fully described by a density function.

Comment: We are truncating at $b$, so whenever we get a number $\ge b$, we write down $b$. Thus $\Pr(U\le b)=1$. For $\Pr(U=b)$, calculate $\int_b^\infty f_Y(y)\,dy$.

Comment: So to sum it up, for CDF of U: when u < b, you use the answer of part A and replace the 'y's with 'u's, right ?  when u >= b, it is one, correct ?

Comment: Yes, you have it precisely right.  Except there is no *law* that you have to use the variable $u$, You could write the cdf of $U$ as $F_U(x)$. Using $u$ for the variable is a useful convention.

Comment: But when I showed this problem to my lecturer, he said the first case (when u < b) is to integrate the pdf of Y (with everything replaced by a dummy) from 0 to b ?? I think the upper limit should be u, right ?

Comment: Yes, if $u\lt b$, for $F_U(u)$, you would integrate the density of $Y$ up to $u$. For $u=b$, you would integrate the density of $Y$ from $b$ to infinity.

Comment: Sorry by saying 'you would integrate the density of Y from b to infinity' you just simply write it as 1, right? As I don't think it is actually possible done without a computer package ?

Comment: I was imprecise in the wording. For the probability that $U$ is **exactly** $b$, you integrate from $b$ to infinity. Or you integrate *up to* $b$, and subtract this from $1$. The density function of $Y$ is easily integrated explicitly, just make the natural substitution. You did it in (a).

Comment: One last question: if you graph the PDF of U, beyond the point b, it is simply zero ? Because you would be 'transferring' all the values beyond y=b to y=b ?

Comment: Please help thanks :)))))

Comment: Sorry, was away. Yes, density the density of $Y$ for $u\lt b$, a point mass at $b$, $0$ density afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

It is a lot simpler than you might think.  Here is a hint:  there are two cases if $U = \min\{Y, b\}$.  Either $Y < b$ or $Y \ge b$.  If the latter, then $\Pr[U = b] = \Pr[Y \ge b] = S_Y(b)$.  Otherwise, $Y < b$ implies $U = Y$ and you already know the density for that situation.

Comment: If $Y \ge b$, then $U = \min\{Y, b\} = b$.  What is the probability that $Y \ge b$?  That is simply $\Pr[Y \ge b]$.  Therefore, the probability that $U = b$ is $\Pr[U = b] = \Pr[Y \ge b]$.  So the distribution of $U$ is partially continuous and partially discrete:  there is a discrete probability mass at $U = b$, and a continuous density for $U < b$ which is identical to the density of $Y$ over the same range.  Think of truncation at $b$ as "collapsing" all of the probability of $Y$ above $b$ into a single discrete probability mass at $b$.

Comment: The CDF of $U$, then, is going to look the same as the CDF of $Y$ for all $U < b$.  When $U \ge b$, the CDF is equal to $1$, since $F_U(u) = \Pr[U \le u]$, and if $u > b$, then $F_U(u) = \Pr[U \le u] = \Pr[U \le b] = 1.$

Comment: $S_Y(b)$ is the survival function of $Y$ at $b$, which is $1 - F_Y(b)$, where $F_Y(b)$ is the CDF of $Y$ at $b$.  I should have written $S_Y(b)$ instead of $S_Y(y)$. I have fixed it now.

Comment: So if you graph the PDF of U, beyond the point b, it is simply zero ? Because you would be 'transferring' all the values beyond y=b to y=b ?

Comment: last question Please help :)

Comment: For the PDF of $U$, yes, because it is impossible to observe $U$ to be larger than $b$.

Answer (score 0):

$Pr(U = b) = Pr(Y \geq b) = \int_{b} ^{\infty} f_Y(y) dy$

$f_U(u) = f_Y(u)$ for $u < b$

Hence, the CDF of $u$ will be ,

$F_U(u) = F_Y(u)$ for $u < b$

$F_U(u) = 1 $ for $u \geq b$ as $F_U(b) = F_Y(b) + Pr(U = b) = 1 $, and it will stay at $1$.

The best way to explain this is that $F_U(u_0)$ is the probability that $u \leq u_0$. So, as the variable $u$ is truncated at $b$, so it will be always less than $b$ and any value greater than $b$.